# Warning: Undefined array key "VENTASUBTOTAL" in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_Mr.GuauGuau\modulos\ventas.php on line 69

Tags: array, undefined

hola buenas tardes estoy intentado imprimir un dato desde una base de datos y me sale este error..
Warning: Undefined array key "VENTASUBTOTAL" in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_Mr.GuauGuau\modulos\ventas.php on line 69
no le encuentro la solucion ya que eh intentado con isset para definir y no se soluciona.. desde ya agradezco sus  comentarios para una  posible solucion.. dejo el codigo para verlo detallado..

```
<?php 
        $sentencia=$query->prepare("SELECT VENTACLIENTE, FECHA, SUM(VENTASUBTOTAL) FROM `ventas` GROUP BY VENTACLIENTE, FECHA");
        $sentencia->execute();
        $selVentas=$sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
        ?>
        <?php foreach($selVentas as $ventas){
           $total=isset($ventas['VENTASUBTOTAL']);
           print_r($total);
            ?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
    
    <thead class="thead-light">
    
        <tr>
            <th>IDVENTA</th>
            <th>CLIENTE</th>
            <th>FECHA</th>
            <th>TOTAL</th>
            <th>....</th>
            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $ventas['VENTACLIENTE'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ventas['VENTACLIENTE'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ventas['FECHA'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $total?></td>
            <td><i class="far fa-edit"></i> <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></td>
        </tr>
     
    </tbody>
    
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
        
            <td colspan="3" align="right">TOTAL</td>
            
               
                <td><?php echo $ventas['VENTASUBTOTAL'];?></td>
            
            
           
        </tr>
        
    </tfoot> 
    <?php } print_r($ventas['VENTASUBTOTAL']);?>
</table>
```

Comment: Realiza un `var_dump()` a `$ventas` y muestranos que contiene

Comment: Estás haciendo un select de `SUM(VENTASUBTOTAL)`, así que esa columna en el resultSet NO se va a llamar VENTASUBTOTAL... hazle un var_dump al array y confirmas qué trae

Comment: realice var_dump($ventas) y me arroja el siguiente resultado:  array(3) { ["VENTACLIENTE"]=> string(4) "pino" ["FECHA"]=> string(19) "2021-04-07 16:00:08" ["SUM(VENTASUBTOTAL)"]=> string(18) "452.44000244140625" }

Comment: hice un print_r($ventas['SUBTOTAL']  y me da el resultado del valor de la suma ejemplo 1667 pero cuando lo quiero imprimir con echo $venta['SUBTOTAL'].. me da este error Warning: Undefined variable $venta in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_Mr.GuauGuau\modulos\ventas.php on line 61 y este otro ... Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_Mr.GuauGuau\modulos\ventas.php on line 61

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta poner un alias a ver como te va, algo como esto

```
$sentencia=$query->prepare("SELECT VENTACLIENTE, FECHA, SUM(VENTASUBTOTAL) as VENTASUBTOTAL  FROM `ventas` GROUP BY VENTACLIENTE, FECHA");
```

Comment: hola intente poner como vos decis: <?php $sentencia=$query->prepare("SELECT VENTACLIENTE, FECHA, SUM(VENTASUBTOTAL) as SUBTOTAL FROM ventas GROUP BY VENTACLIENTE, FECHA"); $sentencia->execute(); $selVentas=$sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ?> <?php foreach($selVentas as $ventas){
               $TOTAL=isset($ventas['SUBTOTAL']);
               var_dump($ventas);
               
                ?> imprimo con echo $ventas['SUBTOTAL']  y me arroja ..Warning: Undefined variable $venta in.... y si imprimo $TOTAL me arroja.. Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

Comment: le pusiste el alias SUBTOTAL con lo cual tambien tendras que  cambiar el nombre VENTASUBTOTAL en todos los lugares donde lo usas

Comment: has un print_r a $selVentas aver como quedo

Comment: ya lo pude solucionar y es que me faltaba un S en  ventas, desde ya que estoy muy  agradecido por la colaboracion...